# Bad initial energy: inf. The model might be misspecified with basic linear regression model in pymc3

Tags: python-3.x, pymc3

I'm trying to build a bayesian inference model in pymc3 and I'm getting the following error:

```
data = [[24, 38.7], [25, 38.6], [26, 38.9], [27, 41.4], [28, 39.7], [29, 41.1], [30, 38.7], [31, 37.6],
        [32, 36.3], [33, 36.9], [34, 35.7], [35, 33.8], [36, 33.2], [37, 30.1], [38, 27.8], [39, 22.8],
        [40, 21.4], [41, 15.4], [42, 11.2], [43, 9.2], [44, 5.4], [45, 3.0], [46, 1.6]]


data = np.array(data)

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
plt.scatter(x, y, color="red")

with pm.Model() as change_point_model:

    switchpoint = pm.DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=x.min(), upper=x.max())

    beta0 = pm.Normal('beta0', mu=40, sd=10)
    beta1 = pm.Normal('beta1', mu=90, sd=10)

    gamma0 = pm.Normal('gamma0', mu=0, sd=5)
    gamma1 = pm.Normal('gamma1', mu=0, sd=5)

    epsilon = pm.Normal('epsilon', mu=0, sd=1)

    intercept = pm.math.switch(switchpoint <= x, beta0, gamma0)
    x_coeff = pm.math.switch(switchpoint <= x, beta1, gamma1)

    y_pred = pm.Normal('y_pred', mu=intercept + x_coeff * x, sd=epsilon, observed=y)

    step1 = pm.NUTS([beta0, beta1, gamma0, gamma1])
    step2 = pm.Metropolis([switchpoint])

    # In this example we are deliberativelly choosing the metropolis sampler
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step=[step1, step2], progressbar=True)

pm.traceplot(trace[100:])
```

And the error that I am getting is the following:

```
ValueError: Bad initial energy: inf. The model might be misspecified.
```

Hence, after doing some readings, I found that `model.logp(model.test_point)` is returning a `-inf`. Hence, how do I solve this error. Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modelling the standard deviation of a normal distribution with a normal. The test point for that is 0.0, which has 0 probability of occurring.

If you change `epsilon` to `Gamma('epsilon', alpha=2.0, beta=0.5)` or similar, you should be fine.